# IndexError: Why am I out of range?

Tags: python

I've been reading other answers for "Index out of range" questions, and from what I understand, you can't try to assign a value to a list index that doesn't exist. My first code was:

```
spam =[]
for i in range(5):
    spam[i]=i
print (spam)
```

After reading some of the other answers, I realized that, when I used just the `range` function, `i` was starting at 0 and couldn't be assigned to the list. So I created the next little bit of code:

```
spam =[]
for i in range(5):
    i += 1
    spam[i]=i
print (spam)
```

And I'm still getting the same error. I know that `i` now gains the value of 1 after the `i += 1` portion of the code, so I believe it should be assigning list item 1 as number 1 in the empty spam list, but it's not working that way. Why is the index not being created?

Comment: Because, as you already claim to understand, *"you can't try to assign a value to a list index that doesn't exist"*. Instead you must `.append` a new element to the end of the list.

Comment: .append was in next chapter. Thanks for the preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
>>> x = []
```

You define `x` as a list. But it is empty.

When you try to run

```
>>> x[i] = i #let assume i is a number
```

That mean that you want to change the value of element number `i` in your array to the value `i`. But the point is that there is no element number `i` in you array. Your array is empty without any element. You can use `append()` method to give an element to your array:

```
>>> x.append(i)
```

Works fine. And then you can change the value of this new element using the previous way. Check this:

```
>>> x  = []
>>> x
[]
>>> i = 0
>>> x[i] = i

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    x[i] = i
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>> x.append(i)
>>> x
[0]
>>> x[i] = i
>>> x
[0]
>>> x[i] = 2
>>> x
[2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`spam=[]` creates an empty list of length 0. Both of your suggested loops are then trying to access an element of the list that does not exist. You probably need to do something like:

```
spam = []
for i in range(5):
    spam.append(i)
```