# Why is my list assignment index out of range in my python app?

Tags: python, dataframe, random, indexing

So imagine I have this code in python:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x_u = []
load_model = open('dt.plk', 'rb')
dt = pickle.load(load_model)
cuantos = int(input('cuantas observaciones: '))
x_u[0] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(341, size = 1))
x_u[1] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(291, size = 1))
x_u[2] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(150, size = 1))
x_u[3] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(301, size = 1))
x_u[4] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(341, size = 1))
x_u[5] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(299, size = 1))
x_u[6] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(150, size = 1))
x_u[7] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(301, size = 1))
ps = dt.predict(x_u)
for d in x_u[0].tolist():
    if d == 0:
        print('Se queda')
    else:
        print('Se va')
```

When I run it I get this error. I've been modifying the index range with no success can you figure out what it is?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
x_u[0] =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(341, size = 1))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Why do you expect it *not* to throw that error? Do you understand what the error is telling you?

Comment: do you need to use `x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(341, size = 1))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexError: Why am I out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917548/indexerror-why-am-i-out-of-range)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a value to a list index that doesn't exist.

If you simply want to assign to those index values in order, you can use `.append()`:

> list.append(x)
>   Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

Thusly modified, your code might look like this:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x_u = []
load_model = open('dt.plk', 'rb')
dt = pickle.load(load_model)
cuantos = int(input('cuantas observaciones: '))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(341, size = 1)))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(291, size = 1)))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(150, size = 1)))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(301, size = 1)))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(341, size = 1)))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(299, size = 1)))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(150, size = 1)))
x_u.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(301, size = 1)))
ps = dt.predict(x_u)
for d in x_u[0].tolist():
    if d == 0:
        print('Se queda')
    else:
        print('Se va')
```

Of course, without your input file, and desired input/output, it's hard to tell if this is what you desire.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please accept the answer, if not, did you find a different solution? If you found a better solution, please post it as an answer to help others with similar questions.